# RestKit handling different HTTP status codes

Tags: ios, http, restkit

I've just started to try out RestKit for an iOS app i'm building. I normally use ASIHttpRequest, but I want to test out RestKit mostly for its object mapping between JSON and CoreData. There are some great things about RestKit, but I've run into an issue that really makes it feel deficient, unless I'm doing something wrong or have missed something. I hope someone here can guide me on that.

I'm using RKObjectLoader to make async & sync calls to a REST API. My service is designed to send back proper HTTP status codes, along with some sort of description, a 401 being an example of when the API needs an authenticated user.

My problem is that RestKit stops acting normally if i get a 401 error back. The RKResponse object has a status code of 0, even though it has a payload in it. I'm pretty sure this comes down to NSURLConnection's poor handling of HTTP statuses, but I would expect RestKit to wrap around this somehow. Especially since the RKResponse class has quite a few wrapper functions to determine the status code of the response (isOK, isCreated, isForbidden, isUnauthorized, etc.).

In comparison, ASIHttpRequest doesn't use NSURLConnection, but instead uses the lower level CFNetwork code. ASIHttpRequest allows me to see exactly what came back over HTTP without sending out errors left & right.

Question is, am I doing something wrong, or is this the expected behavior out of RestKit? Has anyone successfully been able to make a calls to [RKResponse isAuthenticated]? Although its inconclusive to me, is there any difference between running in async and sync mode in this regard. I did read somewhere that NSURLConnection run in sync mode will act a bit differently, even though the underlying code is just calling the async operations. Does this have more to do with me using RKObjectLoader as opposed to just RKRequest? Perhaps the fact that the payload can't map to a model causes anger, but it seems that the code is breaking earlier within RKRequest.sendSynchronously, prior to when mapping actually takes place.

Bottom line is my code needs to be able to freely read HTTP status codes. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Haider

Comment: Are you performing a synchronous or asynchronous call when you're experiencing the issue with a 401 status code? Also, can you post logging output after turning on logging for the various network components via: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network/Queue", RKLogLevelDebug);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network/Cache", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: I can confirm the 0 status code, when actually receiving a 401 status code. I have debugged & traced it, uploaded it to keep the formatting: http://reneras.nl/error.html Does this clear anything up jeffarena ?

Comment: I have the same problem, statusCode 0 and isUnauthorized FALSE, when the server responds 401 because invalid user/password. In other cases (no user/password 401 got read well)

Answer (score 2):

The common way for RestKit 0.20.x is to subclass RKObjectRequestOperation.
I wrote a blog article about this problem which can be found here:
http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2013/09/03/global-request-management-with-restkit/

Answer (score 0):

See http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/msg/839b84452f4b3e26

"... when authentication fails, the authentication challenge gets cancelled and that effectively voids the request."

UPDATE:

RestKit already includes a delegate method for this:

```
(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

Triggers before

```
(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

When HTTP Basic authentication fails, so we can use this instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such method like didFailAuthenticationChallenge (anymore?)